# Conditional sorting xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

My XML file

```
<option>
<options OPT_CD="LAYOUT_SORTBY1_ORDER" OPT_VALUE="DESC"/>
</option>
<data>
<details name="firstName1" address="lastName1" sortby1="firstName"/>
<details name="firstName2" address="lastName2" sortby1="firstName"/>
<details name="firstName3" address="lastName3" sortby1="firstName"/>
</data>
```

My xslt file

```
<xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="option/options[@OPT_CD='LAYOUT_SORTBY1_ORDER']/@OPT_VALUE='DESC'">
             <xsl:apply-templates select="/data/details">
                  <xsl:sort select="./@sortby1" order="descending" />
             </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="/data/details">
                <xsl:sort select="./@sortby1" order="ascending" />
           </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

My requirement

When option is

```
OPT_CD="LAYOUT_SORTBY1_ORDER" and OPT_VALUE="DESC"
```

it should select

```
<xsl:sort select="./@sortby1" order="descending" />
```

else

```
<xsl:sort select="./@sortby1" order="ascending" />
```

Problem:
I am not getting any error message as well as data is not displayed in descending order with condition. Did i made any mistake? Thanks for any suggestion or solution.

Comment: In your sample data, all the `sortby1`s have the same value. Is that the case in your actual data?

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is a typo you have the names the wrong way round

It should not be options/option[]
it should be

option/options

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable and an attribute value template.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:key name="opt" match="@OPT_VALUE" use="../@OPT_CD" />

  <xsl:variable name="sortOrder">
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="key('opt', 'LAYOUT_SORTBY1_ORDER') = 'DESC'">descending</xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>ascending</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/xml">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="data/details">
      <xsl:sort select="@sortby1" order="{$sortOrder}" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="details">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<sup>Note the `<xsl:key>` for convenient option lookup.</sup>

...when applied to

```
<xml>
  <option>
    <options OPT_CD="LAYOUT_SORTBY1_ORDER" OPT_VALUE="DESC"/>
  </option>
  <data>
    <details name="firstName1" address="lastName1" sortby1="firstName1"/>
    <details name="firstName2" address="lastName2" sortby1="firstName2"/>
    <details name="firstName3" address="lastName3" sortby1="firstName3"/>
  </data>
</xml>
```

gives

```
<p>firstName3</p><p>firstName2</p><p>firstName1</p>
```

Comment: It worked for me i just removed <xsl:apply-templates select="data/details"> </xsl:apply-templates> as <xsl:sort is already inside for-each loop. Thanks